# Orchard CMS: How to understand when content item version is actually published?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I need to notify client if new content item version was published. Orchard sends request to client with published content item id, and after that client performs request back to Orchard for this content item data.

I made it by following workflow:

[image: content published workflow]

Web request just sends call with content item id.

I found, that sometimes client receives previous published content item version.
Looks like new published content item version can be accessible only after workflow completely executed.

(Thread.Sleep(1000); in client code resolved this problem). System Cache and Output cache modules are disabled.

Is there some way to understand when content item version is published and actually available from frontend?

Answer (score 0):

When I make custom content parts that have an Orchard.OrchardManagement.ContentItem, using the method of HasPublished(); seems to work.

```
bool i = part.ContentItem.HasPublished();
```